# How to achieve button-click effect on mobile with just css

Tags: html, css

With code below, when tapping the sample element, the sample will go big and then go small, it's nice.
But the question is, when I tap the sample element twice, the effect will only show once.
I know that's because the sample element is still focused, so the animation is not triggered.
I want to solve this with just css, what should I do?

```css
.sample:hover, .sample:focus {
  animation: phoneButtonEffect 0.2s linear;
}
@keyframes phoneButtonEffect {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: _“I want to solve this with just css, what should I do?”_ - accept that that’s not really possible, because CSS can not influence whether an element is in the focus state or not. It can format elements based on certain states, but it can not set or change those states.

Comment: As @misorude said, you cannot do that only with CSS. You need to use js to perform this action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can be achieved with the :active pseudo class.

Take a look at this:

```css
.sample{
 height: 10em;
 width: 10em;
 background-color: red;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.sample:active {
 transform: scale(1.1);
 transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="sample">

 </div>
```

The first **.2s** value is the that the transition will take to be back to normal and the second value **.1s** in the :active selector, is the time that the .sample element will take the reach the desired state, in this case, scale(1.1).